# Accessing Win7 file attributes

Tags: windows, r

I need to read and import in R all available OS attributes for files that are present in a Windows 7 directory.

Attributes I need:

1. Owner

**file.info** is giving me a predefined set of attributes which are only part of what I need, see below:

1. Size
2. isdir
3. mode
4. mtime
5. ctime
6. atime
7. exe

Comment: My question is: How do I do it in R?

Comment: have you looked at `?file.info` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [file.info()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.info.html) to get file information from the computer's file system.

Comment: Can you please provide a generic code for getting the "owner" attribute?

Comment: from `?file.info`: "The ‘uid’, ‘gid’, ‘uname’ and ‘grname’ columns may not be supplied on a non-POSIX Unix-alike system, and will not be on Windows.".  You may be out of luck/need to use a `system()`/`system2()` call to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, will try that out and provide feedback