# Find file owner in r

Tags: r, file, search

There are various base functions for getting info about files. Right now I am using the free software [SearchMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html) in order to do this. However, I would prefer to do it in r.

I would like to search for a specific kind of folder within my hard drive and then I would like to return paths and info about the files found in these folders to a data frame, more specifically, since the files have different owners I would like to return the owners of the files.

The functions that I have tried are `file.info()` and `list.files()`

However, `file.info(path, extra_cols = TRUE)` does not return the owner of the file. Instead it returns this:

```
 size isdir  mode mtime               ctime               atime               exe
10689 FALSE  666  2017-03-01 12:00:47 2017-03-01 12:00:47 2017-03-01 12:00:47  no
```

1) Is there a way to find the owner through `file.info()`

2) Is there a neat way to search all folders with a specific name and return information about the files found in those folders?

Something like

```
list.files(path_to_harddrive, folder_string) %>%
file.info()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105955/accessing-win7-file-attributes-in-r) addresses the issue, however without any accepted answer.

```
> as.data.frame(Sys.info())
                               Sys.info()
sysname                           Windows
release                             7 x64
version        build 7601, Service Pack 1
machine                               x86
```

Comment: You can run `file.info` on a bunch of files using e.g. `sapply(list.files(path_to_harddrive, folder_string), file.info)`. Don't know how to extract the file owner, though.

Comment: You can use something like `system("cmd", input = "dir /q", intern = T)` Parse the big old block of text.

Comment: Great @Vlo that returns the owner, however in a format that is not easily stored into a data frame. Sure, I guess you could clean it up, but there should be an easier way.

Comment: One can decompose raw CMD output into a data frame with substr() function. A bit of data analysis is required (start and end positions), but it is worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided answer was not platform independent, and did not work on Windows network drives for me.

I came up with this code, which uses the `fs` package (by RStudio Team) if not on Windows, and a horrifically ugly script otherwise. Windows can retrieve the owner using the batch command `dir` with the `/Q` flag.

This does the job:

```r
get_owner <- function(path) {
  if (Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Windows") {
    dir <- shell(paste0('dir /Q "', path, '"'), intern = TRUE)
    if (tools::file_ext(basename(path)) == "") {
      # it's a folder
      return(gsub(".*<DIR>[ \t]+([^ ]*).*", "\\1", dir[grepl("<DIR>", dir)][1]))
    } else {
      # it's a file
      return(trimws(gsub(basename(path), "",
                         gsub("^[0-9: \t.-]+", "",
                              dir[grepl(basename(path), dir)]),
                         fixed = TRUE)))
    }
  } else {
    return(fs::file_info(path)$user)
  }
}
```

Then use like this:

```r
get_owner("/Folder/Folder")
get_owner("/Folder/File")
get_owner("C:/Folder/Folder")
get_owner("C:/Folder/File")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the file owners into a dataframe, something like;

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(path = list.files(path_to_harddrive, folder_string)) %>%
    mutate(user = file.info(path)$uname)
```

This seems to be quite slow for me though so I imagine there's a faster way!

Comment: Can't see how this is the accepted answer - `uname` is not even an element in the output of `file.info()`. At least not in Windows, so in the best case it's OS-dependent and only working on (perhaps) UNIX systems.